# I want regex such that it accept any 9 digit number except 123456789 and 987654321

Tags: regex

Acceptable input : any 9 digit number

Not acceptable : `123456789` and `987654321`

I am using `[0-9]{9}` but I want extra condition as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
^(?!123456789|987654321)\d{9}$
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/0vcbtU/1)

---

`^` - beginning of string

`(?!123456789|987654321)` - don't continue matching if `123456789` or `987654321` is found

`\d{9}` - match 9 digits

`$` - end of string

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that, as you only have two exceptions, you write the regex to confirm it's a 9-digit numeric number, and then special case the two edge cases you mention. Not as technically challenging, but much easier to read the code.